# How do I stop villagers from moving away after telling them to?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

In *Animal Crossing: New Horizons* my son accidentally told one of his villagers that they should "follow their dreams" when they said they wanted to leave.  He'd actually like them to stay.

Is there a way to cancel their move and get them to remain on the island?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You actually can stop your villagers from leaving after telling them they should leave!

[According to Reddit user u/deenew](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnimalCrossing/comments/gfnzne/psa_you_can_stop_villagers_from_moving_out_once/), if you talk to the villager who is leaving on the same day that they told you they were leaving on a second player profile, you will get the "should I stay?" option again on the second player. Once you've told them not to go on the second profile, you can return on your resident rep profile, and they will inform you that they've had a change of heart and decided to stay.

[image: Audie telling the player "I decided to stay since Pls Stay asked me not to move away!"]

Comment: Note that this does not apply when a villager gets bumped because you invited a camper. In this case, the bumped villager immediately starts packing the same day and you cannot revert this. I'm the second player on our Switch and talking to the bumped villager did not give me the option to revert their status.

Comment: Ugh this also does not work if the SECOND player tells the villager to follow their heart first. The player that started the island has no recourse if their 2nd player made a bad decision. :[ Adding a 3rd account and player to the island did not help.

Answer (score 8):

Once you answer their question about moving or staying, the decision has been made. In the coming days that islander will pack up and leave. The only way to get them back is through amiibo cards, they come back to a campsite, or you find them again on a Nook island.

Answer (score 1):

Log out immediately without saving and restart the game (go to the home menu and force close the game, DO NOT CLICK THE MINUS TO SAVE AND END) when you log back on find the villager again, and this time you should be able to change your answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yep that works if you haven't seen the circle in the top left, denoting an auto save. What you are basically doing is killing the game before the decision is saved.

Answer (score -1):

Well I fixed that problem. You see to let the villager tell you that he changed his mind you must

1. Go to another ACNH account
2. Find that villager
3. Tell him to stay
4. Wait a couple of minutes
5. Return to your main character,and find that villager again
   And then the villager would run into you and say I changed my mind no more moving out. Simple right

Comment: This answer would be improved by having some punctuation. I have no idea what it's trying to say.